# Postback won't happen in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm using a asp button to upload the file selected with input type file control.

```
<input type="file" id="zipFile" class="zFile" runat="server" title="Browse"
                                    accept="image/jpg" />

<asp:Button ID="Upload21" runat="server" CssClass="Btn" Height="35px" Style="float: left; border-width: 0 !important;
                                        font-size: 12px !important; box-shadow: none; margin: 0 !important;" BorderWidth="0px"
                                         Text="View" OnClick="Upload_Click" OnClientClick="return Validate();"
                                         Width="215px" />
```

My Validate function's logic:

```
if (!$('input[type="file"]').val()) {
    alert('No file to upload');
    return false;
}
else {
    var suffix = '.zip';
    var fileName = $('input[type="file"]').val().toLowerCase();
    if (fileName.indexOf(suffix, fileName.length - suffix.length) == -1) {
        alert('Invalid file selected');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

It works with FF, Chrome and Safari. But even after providing correct file, nothing happens in IE.

Comment: Can you debug the JavaScript to see what's going on? F12 to open the debugger.

Comment: @Rup, it is returning true. So I expect it to do the postback, but it won't.

Comment: Then I'd guess it's getting lost in the ASP.NET code somewhere, which may not be easy to debug. Are you using an old ASP.NET that might not know about IE 10? (I'd be surprised if they didn't go back and update though.)